# Not creating new instances when saving new entities with linked properties in LINQ for EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

I noticed that when I store an object having a property being of another type, it gets saved but so is the linked in property. It's kind of neat when both are new or both are being updated.

```
class Customer
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public List<Category> Categories { get; set; } ...
}

class Category
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; } ...
}
```

However, when I create a new instance of customer but linked to a pre-existing category, it becomes a bit inappropriate. Category in this case is like a tag, so several customers will share a pointer to it and each new customer needs only to reuse the already present category. (If the ID of the category is set as unique, I get error for object already created and when it's not, I get duplicates.)

I understand that it has to do with the state of the objects in relation to EF engine. It simply isn't aware that the category in the new customer is already present in the DB, hence trying to create it.

I played with the status and got into some complicated algorithm, which sort of impacted on readability. Then, I came up with the following approach. I'm not actually doing anything with the data - I simply pull it into the client-side of the EF making it aware of their existence.

```
List<Guid> ids = data.Categories
  .Select(_ => _.Id).ToList();
List<Category> existing = Context.Categories
  .Where(_ => ids.Contains(_.Id)).ToList();
```

To make it simpler, let's assume that the number of the categories is limited, hence reformulating the retrieval to the code below. (It's basically like saying "*Hmmm... Speaking of the categories... Well, nevermind.*", which seems academically wrong.)

```
List<Categories> _ = Context.Categories.ToList();
```

Is there a pattern or approach that is best-practice recommended in this scenario?

I realize that the samples above are just Q&D workaround. The mentioned entity status is complicated. I get the sense that there's a neat way of resolving it.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to load all existing Categories into memory. Rather, just associate the new Customer with the existing Categories he has by loading them from the Context.

```
Guid[] categoryIdsOfNewCustomer; // passed as part of the create command

var newCustomer = new Customer();
newCustomer.Categories = Context.Categories
    .Where(c => categoryIdsOfNewCustomer.Contains(c.Id))
    .ToList();

Context.Customers.Add(newCustomer);
Context.SaveChanges();
```